# PostgreSQL: calculation between first and last

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that calculates the number of days between the first and last score per id.

The data sample:

```
id  date    score
11  1/1/2017    25.34
4   1/2/2017    34.34
25  1/2/2017    15.78
4   3/2/2017    47.2
25  7/3/2017    65.21
11  9/3/2017    96.09
25  10/3/2017   11.3
4   10/3/2017   27.12
```

Which is far from what I need, but I'm really lost. Clueless to be honest. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SELECT 
    customer_id,
    date(last_score) - date(first_score) AS days_between_last_and_first_score,
    total_score::float/(date(last_score) - date(first_score)) AS score_per_day
   FROM
   (
   select customer_id, 
   MAX(date(purchase_date)) as last_score,
   MIN(date(purchase_date)) as first_score,
   SUM(score) AS total_score
   FROM candidate_test_q1
   group by customer_id
  ) AS sub_query
```

Comment: I'm having problems with "DATEIFF", it returns ERROR:  column "day" does not exist. Thank you.

Comment: I have just changed my answer

Comment: Okay, now it works, but it doesn't calculate it by id. I've tried to use your query adding (partition by customer_id order by date(purchase_date) to MAX(date(purchase_date));  MIN(date(purchase_date)); and to SUM(score) but it returns ERROR: dividion by zero. How could it be done properly? Thank you again.

Comment: how come it does not calculate it by ID?. The result of the first sub query is grouped by id (no duplicates) and the external query just performs some calculations. Could you add more context?

Comment: Oh, I missed one line, yes, it's correct as you did!! Sorry, and once again, thank you so much!